# Pysftp/Paramiko "No such file" when repeatedly doing cwd and listdir

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I am writing a Python script (for testing purposes) that, downloads an xml file from a directory, converts it into json, converts it back to xml and uploads it again to a different directory, as long as there is an xml file left in the source directory.

```
def start():
    now = str(datetime.now().strftime("%d%m%Y%H%M%S"))
    try:
        pysftp.Connection(HOST, username=AGENT, password=PW, private_key=".ppk", cnopts=CNOPTS) 
    except:
        print('Connection error')
        return
    xml_data = []
    new_xml = ''
    with pysftp.Connection(HOST, username=AGENT, password=PW, private_key=".ppk", cnopts=CNOPTS) as sftp:
        for filename in sftp.listdir(SOURCE_FOLDER):
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, WILDCARD) and 'cancel' not in filename:
                doc_type = return_doc_type(filename)
                sftp.cwd(SOURCE_FOLDER)
                file_object = io.BytesIO()
                sftp.getfo(filename, file_object)
                xml_file = file_object.getvalue()
                new_xml = xmltodict.parse(xml_file) 
                if new_xml == '':
                    return 
                xml_data.append(new_xml)
                json_data = json.dumps(xml_data)
                new_xml_file = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>' + dict2xml(json.loads(json_data))
                new_xml_file = indent(new_xml_file, indentation = '    ',newline = '\r\n')
                with pysftp.Connection(HOST, username=AGENT, password=PW, private_key=".ppk", cnopts=CNOPTS) as sftp2:
                    with sftp2.cd(DEST_FOLDER):  
                        with sftp2.open(f'test-{AGENT}-{doc_type}-{now}.xml', mode='w+', bufsize=32768) as f:
                            f.write(new_xml_file) 
                            print('xml file deployed on server: ', now, '\n')    
            file_count = len(sftp.listdir(SOURCE_FOLDER))
            if file_count > 3:   
                start()             
            else:
                print('no new files')
                return
```

The `SOURCE_FOLDER` is like `'somefolder/out/'`.

I have tested it with one file and it works, but when I try to make it recursive, I get this error after the 2nd iteration:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../app/views.py", line 232, in start
    file_count = len(sftp.listdir(SOURCE_FOLDER))
  File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 592, in listdir
    return sorted(self._sftp.listdir(remotepath))
  File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 218, in listdir
    return [f.filename for f in self.listdir_attr(path)]
  File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 239, in listdir_attr
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPENDIR, path)
  File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 813, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 865, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File ".../lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 894, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file
```

The original file is in the source directory, so I don't know what *"No such file"* is referring to.

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SOURCE_FOLDER` is a relative path `somefolder/out/`. So say, you start in `/home/path`. Then when you `cwd` to `somefolder/out/`, you end up in `/home/path/somefolder/out/`. If you then `ls` `somefolder/out/`, you are actually referring to `/home/path/somefolder/out/somefolder/out/`, what most probably is not what you want.

And that actually means that even your `for filename` loop cannot work. As you `cwd` to `somefolder/out/` in every iteration, in the second one, it must fail, as it will try to `cwd` to `/home/path/somefolder/out/somefolder/out/`.

You better use absolute paths to avoid this mess.

---

Your code has other issues. For example:

- I do not understand, why you open the second connection to the same host for the upload. You can use the connection you already have.
- `xmltodict.parse` can take a file-like object. There's no need to waste memory by copying `BytesIO` to a string. And actually you do not even need to waste the memory with the `BytesIO`, you can use:

  ```
  with sftp.open(filename, bufsize=32768) as f:
      new_xml = xmltodict.parse(f)
  ```